# Loop over a constant list separated by new lines in bash

Tags: bash

How do I loop over a constant list in bash, where the list is separated by new lines? Something like:

```
for name in (
    aaaaaaaa
    bbbbbbbb
    cccccccc
); do
    echo $name
done
```

Expect this to output:

```
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
cccccccc
```

Comment: Does "constant" mean you can hardcode it in the script?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an array:

```
values=(
    aaaaaaaa
    bbbbbbbb
    cccccccc
)

for name in "${values[@]}"; do
    echo $name
done
```

Or use `\` line joiner:

```
for name in \
    aaaaaaaa \
    bbbbbbbb \
    cccccccc \
; do
    echo $name
done
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Look very familiar, probably used this once upon a time but forgot about them long ago.